# Error in evaluating the test script when retrieving a string from the response in postman

Tags: parameters, postman

From the below response structure i want to retrieve the id field and save it in the environment variable in postman.

I tried all possible methods to do it but unable to do so.

```
{
    "childMaxAge": 13,
    "selectedForBooking": [
        {
            "id": "0661be61-d0ae-411009-a96d-64229a",
            "firstName": "Test",
            "gender": {
                "code": "MALE",
                "name": "Male"
            }
   ]
}
```

i have tried the below and it also doesn't work.

```
tests["Status code is 201"] = responseCode.code === 201;
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(data);
var custid=JSON.parse(data.selectedForBooking[0].id);
tests ["selectedForBooking"]= postman.setEnvironmentVariable("CustId1", custid);
```

but it gives error :

There was an error in evaluating the test script:  JSONError: Unexpected token '6' at 1:2 0661be61-d0ae-411009-a96d-64229a ^

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to parse response data second time.
Also there is no need to use `tests[]` if you're not going to assert anything.

```
tests["Status code is 201"] = responseCode.code === 201;
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(data);
var custid=data.selectedForBooking[0].id;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("CustId1", custid);
```

`var custid=JSON.parse(data.selectedForBooking[0].id);` was trying to make a json object out of `0661be61-d0ae-411009-a96d-64229a` which is not a json formated string.

Comment: Hi, i tried what you suggested but that also giving error "There was an error in evaluating the test script:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Comment: your error indicates that array under "selectedForBooking" is empty, have you checked that response is actually returned?
Is your service publicly available? Can I fire request into it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [POSTMAN : parsing a JSON response, how deep can I go into the response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387112/postman-parsing-a-json-response-how-deep-can-i-go-into-the-response)

I used to have a similar problem, I was trying to reach

```
body.entries[0].attributes.device.type
```

I managed getting the value by doing

```
body.entries[0].attributes['device.type']
```

make sure you use single quotes (I don't know why ...)

Hope this helps

Alexandre

Comment: Hi, i tried what you suggested but that also giving error "There was an error in evaluating the test script: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Comment: well, it's not exaclty the same case as mine, have you tried to console.log(custid) before the test ? with this error, it looks like selectedForBooking[0] is not recognized ... could you also have a look, in the console, to selectedForBooking[0] ?

Comment: ?? why do you json.parse data, which is already the result of a json parsing ?

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON data itself is wrong, that is why it was showing that error.

It Must be :

```
{
    "childMaxAge": 13,
    "selectedForBooking": [
        {
            "id": "0661be61-d0ae-411009-a96d-64229a",
            "firstName": "Test",
            "gender": {
                "code": "MALE",
                "name": "Male"
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

Now u can try this

`var custid=data.selectedForBooking[0].id;`

It will return the required value